# How to present UIViewController from viewController's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the view of a `UITableViewController` in a `UIViewController` as can be seen below:

```
UITableViewController *tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:tvc.view];
```

Now, inside this `UITableViewController` I'd like to be able to present a `SFSafariViewController` if necessary. I wrote the code below:

```
if (showLink) {
    SFSafariViewController *sfsvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
    [self.presentingViewController.navigationController pushViewController:sfsvc animated:YES];
}
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error in the console and nothing happens:

```
[Warning] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFSafariViewController: 0x7f8aef82a600>)
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Why are you not just using a `UITableView` instead of hacking a `UITableViewController`?  Your problem is that you safari view controller is a local variable and it being released as soon as this function exits, presumably because nothing is retaining your tableviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rootViewController` to push `SFSafariViewController` is a solution for you in this case. Try my code below

```
if (showLink) {
    SFSafariViewController *sfsvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window;
    [rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:sfsvc animated:YES];
}
```